# OpenCV detected faces are not at the same position for identical images

Tags: node.js, opencv, face-recognition

I am in the process of building a Npm package ([Facematch](https://github.com/webjay/facematch)) that utilizes OpenCV to find the difference between two images.

The code I have written seems to work, but the results seem often very wrong, and if I output the detected face it is not always found in the same area of the image. I rarely get an absDiff of 0 even if I compare two equal images of Mona Lisa.

```
var cv = require('opencv');
var async = require('async');

function Facematch () {

  this._detectObjects = function (im, callback) {
    var object, img;
    var options = {
      scale: 2
    };
    im.detectObject(cv.FACE_CASCADE, options, function (err, objects) {
      if (err) return callback(err);
      // console.log(objects);
      if (objects.length === 0) return callback('No objects found');
      for (var i in objects) {
        object = objects[i];
        img = im.roi(object.x, object.y, object.width, object.height);
        self.faces.push(img);
      }
      callback();
    });
  };

  this._calcDiff = function (callback) {
    var im1 = self.faces[0];
    var im2 = self.faces[1];
    // im1.save('im1.jpg');
    // im2.save('im2.jpg');
    var diff = new cv.Matrix(im1.width(), im1.height());
    diff.absDiff(im1, im2);
    diff.convertGrayscale();
    callback(null, diff.countNonZero());
  };

  var self = this;
  this.ims = [];
  this.faces = [];

}

Facematch.prototype.compare = function (img1, img2, callback) {

  var self = this;
  var images = [img1, img2];
  var diff;

  async.series([
    function (callback) {
      async.map(images, cv.readImage, function (err, results) {
        if (err) return callback(err);
        self.ims = results;
        callback();
      });
    },
    function (callback) {
      async.each(self.ims, self._detectObjects, callback);
    },
    function (callback) {
      if (self.faces.length < 2) return callback('Not enough faces');
      self._calcDiff(function (err, result) {
        if (err) return callback(err);
        diff = result;
        callback();
      });
    }
  ], function (err) {
    callback(err, diff);
  });

};


var imgFiles = ['Mona.jpg', 'Mona.jpg'];
var imgs = imgFiles.map(function (img) {
  return __dirname + '/images/' + img;
});

var fm = new Facematch();
fm.compare(imgs[0], imgs[1], function (err, diff) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('Images absDiff is %d', diff);
});
```

**Update**

If I pass `{ scale: 2 }` as options to `detectObject` Mona Lisa matches, but with other images it can't find a face. 
I guess this means that images should be scaled to have the same size before they are compared?

Comment: Here's Mona: https://github.com/webjay/facematch/blob/master/test/images/Mona.jpg

Comment: are those jpg images ? lossy compression will wreck any attempt at comparing pixel-wise.

Comment: yes, have a look at Mona. I do get absDiff 0, but rarely, which I find very strange.

Comment: When I run the test I get `Images absDiff is 4574`. It's often between 3000 and 5000.

Comment: did you know, that opencv already comes with builtin face-recognition ?

Comment: Yes, isn't that what I'm using? `im.detectObject(cv.FACE_CASCADE` or is there something else I should use?

I've read that Features2d should be best for matching different photos of the same person.

Comment: that's *detection*, not [regognition](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/contrib/doc/facerec/index.html)

Comment: ah, thanks. Good luck to me translating it to Node.js :)

Comment: it's even in the [bindings already](https://github.com/peterbraden/node-opencv/blob/master/src/FaceRecognizer.cc). just don't expect me to know how to use it

Comment: ah ok I get it, you don't compute absDiff on the same images but on detected faces? So the question should be that faces aren't detected/recognized at the same locations (for identical images)?!?

Comment: @Micka yes, that's the problem.